# not changing textbox value from ui

Tags: javascript, html

taking value in 1st textbox and want to display it in 2nd..

```
1st <input type="text" value=" " id = "marks1" name = "marks1" onblur = "myFunction('marks1')"     />
2nd <input type="text" value=" " id = "marks2" name = "marks1" disabled = "disabled"   />
```

and on `oblur` I am calling a function.
Whenever I change the value from UI, on function call I am getting the old value i.e. `' '` instead of changed value.
in the variable "value" the old value which i am getting, i am unable to display it on 2nd textbox.

```
function myFunction( txtname ) { 
    alert("call");
    var txtobj = document.getElementsByName(txtname);
    var value = txtobj[0].value;
    alert("my value : "+value);
    txtobj[1].value =  value;
}
```

I know the code is okay, but it is not working at me. Is there any other way?

Comment: Why did you edit it and remove the function call? I fixed it. and made all of the i's, I.

Comment: I'm not able to duplicate this in Chrome (see fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UBUbj/). What browser is this happening in?

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to pass the name, you can pass the object.

```
<input type="text" value=" " id="marks1" name="marks1" onblur="myFunction(this)" />
```

and the function

```
function myFunction( txtobj ) { 
    alert("my value : " + txtobj.value);
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/StbS7/)

Answer (score 0):

To this page you can find a working example http://jsfiddle.net/Akj2M/

In any case your code is good because passing the name or passing the object `this` is the same.

```
<input type="text" value=" " id = "marks1" name = "marks1" onblur="myFunction('marks1')"/>

<script>
    var myFunction = function myFunction( txtname ) {
    alert("call");
    var txtobj = document.getElementsByName(txtname);
    alert("my value : "+txtobj[0].value);
}
</script>​
```