# not changing textbox value from ui and unable to display

Tags: javascript, html

taking value in 1st textbox and want to display it in 2nd..

```
1st <input type="text" value=" " id = "marks1" name = "marks1" onblur = "myFunction('marks1')"     />
2nd <input type="text" value=" " id = "marks2" name = "marks1" disabled = "disabled"   />
```

and on oblur I am calling a function. Whenever I change the value from UI, on function call I am getting the old value i.e. ' ' instead of changed value.
in the variable "value" the old value which i am getting, i am unable to display it on 2nd textbox.

```
function myFunction( txtname )
{ 
    alert("call");
    var txtobj = document.getElementsByName(txtname);
    var value = txtobj[0].value;
    alert("my value : "+value);
    txtobj[1].value =  value;
}
```

I know the code is okay, but it is not working at me. Is there any other way?

Comment: `name` and `id` share the same namespace. If they are both used for an element they should be identical. You're using `name` where `class` would be more appropriate.

Comment: You already posted the a question with the same problem! [not changing textbox value from ui](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9718748/not-changing-textbox-value-from-ui)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works for me:

```
function myFunction(element)
{ 
    var txtobj = document.getElementsByName(element);
    var value = txtobj[0].value;
    txtobj[1].value =  value;
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pwTwB/1/

Are you getting an error?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to set the next textbox's value.

```
function moveText(ele){

    document.getElementById("marks2").value = ele.value;

}
```

Then use the following in your html markup

```
<input type="text" id="marks1" onblur="moveText(this)" />
<input type="text" id="marks2" disabled="disabled" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
function myFunction( txtname )
{ 
    var txtobj = document.getElementById(txtname);
    var target = document.getElementById("marks2");
    target.value = txtobj.value;
}
```